# ICEFaces tag not rendering in xhtml (JSF 2.2 and ICEFaces 3.3.0)

Tags: xhtml, icefaces

I'm using ice faces 1.8 app example.

pom is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>tab</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces.netbeans.rave</groupId>
            <artifactId>wyswyg-appbase</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>just-ice</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces-comps</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>icefaces-facelets</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml is empty:

 
if I put this on it

```html
    <application>
        <view-handler>com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler</view-handler>

    </application>
```

the app throws this exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
 Unable to create a new instance of 'com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">


</faces-config>
```

index.xhtml is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:ace="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
        >
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
    <ice:outputText value="hello world ice outputtext"/>
</h:form>
</html>
```

the problem is that when I run this and the xhtml is generated, only the h tag "Hello, world" is rendered.
the ice faces tag (ice:outputText) is not rendered because in the xhtml code, it still as is it.

[image]

I tried every posted solution that I found in the web for the las 4 days bud nothing worked for me.

I try ICEFaces 3.x, different name spaces, tomcat 6/7, etc

I'm using Intellij 14 and Tomcat 6.0.44

Please, let me know what if somebody finds what I'm doing wrong/missing and if you need any other info from my app/enviroment.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What I was trying to do was to use (and render of course ) a composite component.

I finally solved using templates for the composite components: 
 this is the structure on the template.xhtml

```html
<h:head>
  ...
</h:head>

<h:body>
  <div class="[name1]">
    <h:form>
      <ui:insert name="[name2]"/>
    </h:form>
  </div>
</h:body>
```

and using it in the main form as this:

```html
<ui:composition ...
                xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/componentes"
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="name2">
    <ice:[any ice component]>
      </ice:[any ice component]>
  </ui:define>
```

may be form tags in the template are not necessary and even template are not, bud after hours and hours surfing the web this is the way I solved.

Any further detail needed, just ask. Or if anyone has a better way to do this, will be very welcome.

Regards!